# Active record dates between "reversed"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Community

I'd like to know if there is a way (apart from the raw sql) to do a query like this

```
    SELECT * FROM
    mydb.afiliados AS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    afiliacionvehiculo AS av ON av.idAfiliado = A.idAfiliado
WHERE a.idAfiliado = 3 AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN av.fechaInicio AND av.fechaFinal;
```

I tried this

```
date=Date.new
@afiliados=Afiliado.joins(:persona, :afiliacionvehiculos).where(afiliacionvehiculos: {date :fechaInicio..:fechaFinal })
```

But this is what I get.

```
SyntaxError in AfiliadoController#index
    /Users/cristiantorres/Documents/pruebaRailsTransporte/app/controllers/afiliado_controller.rb:4:
 syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => ...re(afiliacionvehiculos: {date :fechaInicio..:fechaFinal }) ... ^
 /Users/cristiantorres/Documents/pruebaRailsTransporte/app/controllers/afiliado_controller.rb:4: 
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end ...ate :fechaInicio..:fechaFinal }) ... ^
```

I know that pass a raw sql string should work, but if anyone know another way I'd be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I did not understand the language properly, sorry about that.*

But, your syntax for date range is wrong. You can pass date range in active record like this:

```
date: from_date..to_date
```

So, your query will be something like this:

```
Afiliado.joins(:persona, :afiliacionvehiculos).where(date: fechaInicio..fechaFinal)
```

If your `afiliacionvehiculos` table has the `fechaInicio` and `fechaFinal` columns, then you can also do this:

```
Afiliado.joins(:persona, :afiliacionvehiculos).where('CURRENT_DATE between afiliacionvehiculos.fechaInicio and afiliacionvehiculos.fechaFinal')
```

Comment: Thank you for spend your time in my question, really useful answer

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Don't forget to accept an answer. To see how it works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: finally, I used this and worked flawlessly, is not the exact answer you give me, but your answer brought me to the desired query 

@afiliados=Afiliado.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN personas ON personas.idPersonas = afiliados.Personas_idPersonas '\
    'left outer join afiliacionvehiculo  on afiliacionvehiculo.idAfiliado = afiliados.idAfiliado '\
    'and CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN afiliacionvehiculo.fechaInicio and afiliacionvehiculo.fechaFinal').distinct()

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Rails does not work like this.

If you use the hash syntax in `where` then Rails always expects that the `key` is the name of a column (and not a `SQL` statement) and that the values are values to check against (and not database column names).

Even the simples `where('CURRENT_DATE' => ('foo'..'bar'))` would translate to:

```
WHERE (\"baz\".\"CURRENT_DATE\" BETWEEN 'article' AND 'aside')"
```

And there is no way around this, because this kind of *Rails magic* where table names are added and values are escaped are a security feature.

Therefore the only solution is to write the condition partly in `SQL`:

```
where('CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN av.fechaInicio AND av.fechaFinal')
```

Comment: Thanks, after a couple of frustating hours I began to suspect that there were no answer but raw sql,  you make it clear for me